# LinkedStacks in python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

[image]

This code is for Stack using single linked lists

From 27 and 30 I don't understand what is happening

Let's say I do this

```
a=LinkedStack()
a.push(1)
a.push(2)
a.push(3)
```

In first push a._head._element=1 and a._head._next=1

In second push a._head._element=2 and a._head._next=a.head

Isn't this absurd

I don't understand this 
Please help
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's absurd about it? The old head is made into the tail of the new head. Also, please always post code as text, not images.

Comment: But old value is lost

Comment: I am really sorry about the formatting I have taken this code from a book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self._head = self._Node(e, self._head)
```

This could be broken down to

```
new_head = self._Node(e, self._head)  # Step 1

self._head = new_head  # Step 2
```

Note what's given to the new head: the old head which contains the entire list.

If you had a list like

```
9 -> 8 -> 7
```

And you pushed a `1` to it, you'd get

```
1 -> 9 -> 8 -> 7
```

"Step 1" above says "take the old head, and make it the tail of the new head". The data isn't lost, it's just stored in `self._head._next` instead of `self._head`.

Comment: If I had to access 7 how would I get it ?

Comment: @HarshitGupta Are you asking how you'd get the head if you have access to the node holding 7 (the last node in the list)?

Comment: Let's say I want to get 3rd node then how would I geet it

Comment: Is the code doing this ? First it makes a._head._next container of old object then it reassigns the a._head to new object which contain previous object as a._head._next and a._head._element

Comment: If I want third node then I have to unpack three times ?

Comment: @HarshitGupta The third node would be `self._head._next._next`. And yes, that sounds correct.